# Handlebars access variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Let's say I have an object with two items:

`state : {
    'action-foo-collapsed' : 1,
    'action-bar-collapsed': 1
}`

In handlebars, I'm iterating over another object where the keys correspond with `foo` and `bar`.

I would like to access the object as shown above in a dynamic way, something like this:

`{{#if @root.state['action-' @key '-collapsed']}}`

Is this achievable, preferable without the use of custom helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [Lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) built-in helper for dynamic parameter resolution. However, your case is a little more complicated because you want to concatenate some strings to create your `state` key. It would be easier if your `state` object had the *same* keys as your other object. That would allow you to do the following:

```
{{#if (lookup @root.state @key)}}

{{/if}}
```

Note that the above uses Handlebars' Subexpressions which allows us to pass the result of the `lookup` helper to the `if` helper.

Unfortunately, Handlebars does not have a built-in helper for concatenating strings. If the keys of your `state` object *must* be as they are in your question, then you will need to create a helper that will allow you to concatenate. Such a helper is fairly simple, here is one that I came up with:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join('');
});
```

Using this helper, we can access the keys of your `state` object as follows:

```
{{#if (lookup @root.state (concat 'action-' @key '-collapsed'))}}

{{/if}}
```

For reference, I have created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/n445hyfz/) that uses both methods described above to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks. The solution was indeed using `lookup` and using the same key in the state object.